# noDataText in react-bootstrap-table-next does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I need to show "There is no data to display" in the table body.

I am now using react-bootstrap-table-next which is an advanced version of react-bootstrap-table

```
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next'
...
<BootstrapTable
    keyField="id"
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    expandRow={expandRow}
    options={{ noDataText: 'There is no data to display' }}
/>
```

It does not show wanted text when there is no data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
const emptyDataMessage = () => { return 'No Data to Display';}
```

`<BootstrapTable noDataIndication={emptyDataMessage} ../>`